# I can't make my program go back to its menu

Tags: python-2.7

I made this small calculator to tell people about their calories and body weight index and other things, but when i want to use the function regresarMenu() it doesn't take me back to the menu, it shows me an error that says "str" is not callable, and i don't know how to figure out a way to loop it back to the menu

```
import time
import sys

print("")
print("Bienvenido a la calculadora saludable")
print("Debe llenar la siguiente informacion para proceder ")
print("") 
peso = int(raw_input("ingrese su peso en kilogramos: "))
estatura = float(raw_input("ingrese su estatura en metros: "))
nombre = raw_input("ingrese su nombre: ")
edad = int(raw_input("ingrese su edad: "))
sexo = raw_input("ingrese masculino si es hombre y femenino si es mujer: ")


def imc():

    imc = peso/(estatura*estatura)
    print("Calculando el indice de masa corporal, espere unos segundos")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("")
    print (("Saludos "+ nombre +" su indice de masa corporal es    de")+str(imc))
    print("")

    if(imc<18):
        print(nombre+" su peso es bajo, necesario valorar signos de     desnutricion")

    elif(18<imc<24.9):
        print(nombre+" se encuentra en un nivel de peso normal")

    elif(25<imc<26.9):
        print(nombre+" se encuentra con sobrepeso")

    elif(27<imc<29.9):
        print(nombre+ " esta en el rango de obesidad grado I")
        print("El reisgo para desarollar enfermedades cardiovasculares es relativamente alto")

    elif(30<imc<39.9):
        print(nombre+ " esta en el rango de obesidad grado II")
        print("El reisgo para desarollar enfermedades cardiovasculares es muy alto")

    else:
        print(nombre+ " esta en el rango de obesidad grado III, extrema o morbida")
        print("El reisgo para desarollar enfermedades")
        print("cardiovasculares es extremadamente alto")

    print("")
    regresarMenu()


def peso_ideal():
    altura = estatura*100
    pesoIdeal = 0.75*(altura-150)+50
    rango1 = float(pesoIdeal-7)
    rango2 = float(pesoIdeal+7)
    print("") 
    print (nombre+ " su peso ideal deberia de estar entre "+str(rango1)+" y "+str(rango2)+"kg")
    print("")
    regresarMenu()

def calorias():
    altura = estatura*100
    if(sexo == "masculino"):
        TMB = float(10*peso)+(6.25*altura)-(5*edad)-161
        print("")
        print("Las calorias que utiliza durante el dia son: "+ str(TMB))
    if(sexo == "femenino"):
        TMB = float(10*peso)+(6.25*altura)-(5*edad)+5
        print("")
        print("Las calorias que utiliza durante el dia son: "+str(TMB))
    print("") 
    print (nombre+ " su peso ideal deberia de estar entre "+str(rango1)+" y "+str(rango2)+"kg")
    print("")
    regresarMenu()



def menu():
    print("")
    print("*********************************************************")
    print("*    ******** ********* *          ********  *        * *")
    print("*   *         *       * *         *          *        * *")
    print("*  *          *       * *        *           *        * *")
    print("*  *          *       * *        *           *        * *")
    print("*  *          *       * *        *           *        * *")
    print("*  *          ********* *        *           *        * *")
    print("*  *          *       * *        *           *        * *")
    print("*  *          *       * *        *           *        * *")
    print("*   *         *       * *         *          *        * *")
    print("*    ******** *       * ********   ********   ********  *")
    print("*********************************************************")
    print("")
    print("")
          print("******************************************************************")
    print("* 1) Si desea calcular su IMC presione 1                         *")
    print("* 2) Si desea encontrar su peso ideal presione 2                 *")
    print("* 3) Si desea ver la cantidad de calorias que utiliza presione 3 *")
    print("*                                                                *")
    print("******************************************************************")
    respuesta = raw_input("")

    if(respuesta == "1"):
        imc()
    if(respuesta == "2"):
        peso_ideal()    
    if(respuesta == "3"):
        calorias()

def regresarMenu():
    menu = raw_input("Desea regresar al menu? ingrese si/no ")
    if(menu == "si"):
        print("")
        print("regresando al menu, espere un momento")
        time.sleep(3)
        menu()
    if(menu == "no"):
        System.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that you are using a variable named menu and a function named menu as well at "regresarMenu" function. What you have to is to rename one of them; for example:

```
def regresarMenu():
    menu_option = raw_input("Desea regresar al menu? ingrese si/no ")
    if(menu_option == "si"):
        print("")
        print("regresando al menu, espere un momento")
        time.sleep(3)
        menu()
    if(menu_option == "no"):
        System.exit()
```

Comment: how could i not see that?! Thanks a lot @dgsleeps